# Inside a thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-1.9.3

In the following code, I expect 1000 lines of `'a'` to be printed, but it does not output anything. Without `Thread.new{` and `}`, it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
Thread.new{1000.times{puts 'a'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a thread that will print `a` 1,000 times, but then what do you do? If your program terminates before that thread gets a chance to run, nothing will be printed.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
Thread.new{1000.times{puts 'a'}}.join
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer adds additional information on top of David's, and is helpful. I accepted David's because it was earlier.